# Why do I get 'None' as the output from a print statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, syntax, nonetype

```
def print_name(name):
    print(name)

print(print_name('Annabel Lee'))
```

Why do I get the following output:

```
Annabel Lee
None
```

More precisely, from where does the word `None` come from?

Comment: The function `print_name` returns `None` since no return is specified. You print the return value in your final print statement.

Comment: `None` isn't the output; it's the return value. The two concepts are *completely* different. The confusion is that the interactive interpreter, when evaluating a function call, prints its return value to standard output.

Answer (score 2):

You have two calls to `print`: one inside `print_name` and another outside the function's scope.

The one inside `print_name()` prints the `name` passed in. The one on the outside prints what the function `print_name` returns - which is `None` as you have no `return` statement. Presuming you want only one printed output, you'd `return` it instead of printing it in the function:

```
def print_name(name):
    return name

print(print_name('Annabel Lee'))
```

Or just call `print_name` without wrapping it in a `print` function.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are print the method `print`, the return should be name, not `print(name)`.

Answer (score 1):

Your function is not returning anything that's why it is giving None.
An non-returning function is returned with None.

Answer (score 1):

Your function prints the name and you don't need to use `print()` again.

```
def print_name(name):
    print(name)

print_name('Annabel Lee')
```

If don't use `return` in a function, it returns `None` by default. Your code was correct if your function was like this:

```
def print_name(name):
    return name

print(print_name('Annabel Lee'))
```

Answer (score 0):

The `print()` function evaluates the arguments in the parentheses and print the result.
`print(1+1)` will print "2", since the result of 1+1 is 2. Just like that, `print("abcd".upper())` will print "ABCD".

When you call `print(print_name('Annabel Lee'))`, the print function tries to evaluate the argument, in this case, `print_name('Annabel Lee')`. Since the `print_name()` function does not return any value (it just prints 'Annabel Lee'), the returned value is None. This is why the `print()` function print "None".